# How to get the even item positions in a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list like this

```
List<double> points1 = new List<double>
{
  10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100
};
```

How can I get the even positions with LINQ in order to get a list like this

```
20,40,60,80,100
```

I know how to do it with a for loop, but I want this in a single line with LINQ

Comment: Remove them from the existing list?  Or produce a new one?  LINQ tends not to have side-effects and so seems like the wrong tool for in-place modifications.

Comment: I want to produce a new one, but removing is also good

Comment: The edit doesn't clarify that and now the title is asking something different than the body of the question.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews sorry, I fixed the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
points1.Where((value, idx) => idx % 2 != 0);
```

Comment: I would suggest using discard for first parameter `points1.Where((_, idx) => idx % 2 != 0);`

Comment: Unless one doesn't take the requested "list" in the question to mean specifically a `List<double>`, this answer seems like an incomplete thought.  The typical way to produce one would be to tack `.ToList()` on the end, but even though we can predict the size of the new list, `ToList()` cannot and may have to resize along the way.  Though more cumbersome, `new List<double>(points1.Count / 2).AddRange(points1.Where((value, idx) => idx % 2 != 0))` creates a right-sized list up-front.